# colour spheres according to data

Tags: matlab

i have a 622x5 array, where columns 1 to 4 contain the x, y, z and radius of the sphere, column 5 contains the average force on the surface of the sphere. what i want to do is generate the spheres using x,y,z,r but then colour the spheres using the final column of the array. I know how to create spheres in matlab using the following code:

```
[x y z] = sphere;
AA=load('C_Lx_Avg.txt');

nn=length(AA(:,1));
for i=1:nn
  surf(x*AA(i,4)+AA(i,1),y*AA(i,4)+AA(i,2),z*AA(i,4)+AA(i,3));
  if (i==1); hold on; end;
end

shading interp
axis equal
camlight
lighting phong

set(gca,'FontSize',[16],'FontWeight','bold')
print fig01 -dpdf
```

But what i am not sure how to do is use the final column of the array to colour the spheres.

Comment: That's clearly not C. Don't spam tags!

Comment: Well the reason i tagged in c is because if there is any other way of doing what i want, i have tried it in matlab and preview. not sure if anyone can guide me to a c code that can do this or basically advise on how to do this in matlab. Thats all really

Comment: For the record, please don't duplicate questions. If you don't get enough attention for one, edit it to make it better instead of reasking it. I closed your old one since this one is now answered.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry i am new to this site and new to coding. thank you very much for your help and advice, i will adhere to it from now. Once again thanks

Comment: Not a ParaView question. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) command to specify the [`'CData'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#inputarg_C) like so:

```
surf(x*AA(i,4)+AA(i,1), y*AA(i,4)+AA(i,2), z*AA(i,4)+AA(i,3), AA(i,5).*ones(size(x)));
```

This will give each sphere a color based on the current [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) of the axes, mapped from lowest to highest value, which you can display with [`colorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html). Using `AA = [1 1 1 0.5 3; 0 0 0 1 1];` and adding a colorbar, here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what i needed, thank you so much.